# Can't use ideone to demonstrate that code from question actually compiles

Tags: bug, answers, hyperlinks

In some cases, the code I'm placing on ideone is from the question itself.  But SO won't let me post a link without adding code to my answer.

Clearly the "code required in answer" decision neglected to consider this use case.

Yes, I can workaround it by saying:

```
Code block to workaround stupid requirement
enforced on answers containing ideone links.
```

but that is really ugly.

Is there any better way to handle this scenario?

Comment: What value is an answer that simply says code in the question compiles? Possibly makes both the question and answer seem useless, doesn't it?

Comment: What you're describing is a comment.

Comment: Yet you've figured [a really elegant workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15824443/335858) to this problem :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: It's still a workaround, and only made sense because the question's code wasn't quite a minimal repro.

Comment: @Bill: Ok, then should the warning message suggest making a comment, instead of suggesting including code in the answer?  But when the premise of the question is that there IS an error, I feel a positive demonstration resolves it.  (People have been known to post questions "why can't I do xyz?" with working code)

Comment: When an observation resolves the question, I tend to make it an answer, no matter how short.  Is that wrong?

Comment: If the observation is that "your code works," that's not an answer. If that's all the question *needs*, then it's also typically not a question that will ever help anybody, making it too localized or NARQ.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's not a bad idea.  If it's going to block you from posting an answer, the message should probably at least mention that it might be better posted as a comment, particularly if it sees a link to ideone, jsfiddle, etc.